# Is $(n+1)! = \mathrm{o}(n^n)$?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, exponentiation, factorial

Continuing http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2431263, it seems to me that you can prove with the same method that $(n+1)! = o(n^n)$.

Namely:

Let $a_n=\frac{(n+1)!}{n^n}$. Then:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+2)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{(n+1)!}{n^n}}=\frac{n^n(n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \to \frac{1}{e}\cdot 1 <1$$

Thus from ratio test for sequences we have that $a_n \to 0$.

Can anyone confirm or reject this?

Comment: Yes, by Stirlings formula.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Stirling's formula gives you $o((n+1)^{n+1})$, though, at least immediately. That's not the same.

Comment: @Arthur There is a factor of $e^{-n-1}$ in Stirlings formula and $e^{-n-1}n^{k} \to 0$ for every $k$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy: Stirling is a sledgehammer to solve this.

Comment: In fact, $(cn+k)!\in o(n^n)$ for any constants $c\in(0,\,e),\,k\ge0$, since $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\sim en$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare

$$LHS=\color{green}2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots n\cdot\color{green}{(n+1)}$$ and $$RHS=\color{green}n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot n\cdots \color{green}n$$ ($n$ factors each).

Now it is clear that $LHS=o( RHS)$ just because $\color{green}2\cdot\color{green}{(n+1)}=o(\color{green}{n\cdot n})$ and all intermediate factors are smaller or equal.

---

More generally, for any constant $k$, $(n+k)!=o(n^n)$.

Comment: I can't follow your "it is clear" sentence. For starters, this is what the question is asking! Secondly, I can't see how to apply the "just because" bit.

Comment: He's saying that $n!/2\leq n^{n-2}$, since it's a product of $n-2$ terms, each of which is at most $n$. Hence, all you need to prove is that $2(n+1)=o(n^2)$, but this is easy.

Comment: More generally, $n!/k!\leq n^{n-(k+1)}$ and $k!\prod_{j=1}^{k} (n+j)=o(n^{k+1})$.

Comment: @user1729: I have added clarification.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is close, but it seems more satisfying to use $\frac{n+2}{n}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}}$ as the ratio because it gives telescoping inequalities.

---

Let
$$
a_n=\frac{(n+1)!}{n^n}\tag1
$$
then, because $\frac{n+2}{n}\le\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2$ (expand the square) and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\ge e$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), which says that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ decreases to $e$),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
&=(n+2)\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{n+2}{n}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}}\\
&\le\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\frac1e\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, telescopically, we have
$$
a_n\le a_1\frac{n^2}{e^{n-1}}\tag3
$$
and since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{e^{n-1}}=0\tag4
$$
we get that $(n+1)!=o\!\left(n^n\right)$